# C++ pointer to function with reference return type

Tags: c++, clion

I want to writer a pointer to function, with reference return type

```
string & cmp(string &s1, string &s2) {
    return s1.size() > s2.size() ? s1 : s2;
}
```

function cmp is simple, it just return the longer string.

```
string string1 = "123";
string string2 = "1234";

string & (*pf)(string &,string &) = cmp;
```

it's ok to call

```
string &temp = cmp(string1, string2);
```

but when I try to use `pf`,

```
string &temp = pf(string1, string2);
```

compiler shows error: `expression must be lvalue`

**added:** sorry, it seems that the IDE provide the wrong inspection information.

[image]

I'm using CLion as IDE, The red underline shows error, but actually I can compile it and run successfully....It's weird, anybody know what's wrong with my IDE inspection? Or maybe I need to post issue at CLion community?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you mention, for me this compiles and runs just fine?!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your snippets are not enough information to reproduce your problem, as you can see [here](https://tio.run/##bU9BDsIgELzzik1NGjDVCHqyWt9CKG1ICpJCLxrfjjQtTU3dyw4zO8uOsPYgOm7aEHbKiG6oJdzU0/lecl2hwSnTguFaOsuFBOfrEqGojnQOQlucHo4WsGBG4I0gVi/90Btw9OjUS2ICFTiW8CPycI1EiT4IKeNBc2Vw8s7bpkbhDhll56zcamzWLlFcqzngvW3IcmKRAImGePvPqtxLbSd@NiyBGNlMjl/a5t/gOvYpBgvhCw)

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @lubgr  sorry it seems that my IDE gives wrong inspection error....see my update

Comment: Well, if you think it's a bug, check your IDE settings twice and if you can't fix this warning, you might want to report it to JetBrains.

Comment: and, please do not upload pictures of the codes.

Comment: Seems like it is just a bug in the CLion inspecting thingy

Answer (score 0):

I think CLion just considered the function call as an rvalue by default (even though it does return an lvalue reference). However **do never use function pointers in C++**, [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is here to avoid C function pointers' messy syntax or you can just write

```
auto pf = cmp;
```

or

```
auto& pf = cmp;
```

Not sure which one is recommended though but my guess would be `auto&` as `cmp` is an rvalue.

Comment: `std::function` is a heavy type-erasing functionoid container. It should absolutely not be used as a blanket replacement for function pointers. You can use `template <class F> using fptr = F *;` if you want the convenient `fptr<int(int)> pf` syntax.

Comment: @Quentin on the other hand it's easy to use; IMO it's a good default unless you have the need to micro-optimize

Answer (score 0):

I tried it, all you have to do is to remove the & from the variable in the main function:

```
string& (*pf)(string &,string &) = cmp;
string temp = pf(string1, string2);
```

But I have tried something else which worked too:

```
string& (*pf)(string &,string &) = cmp;
string &temp = cmp(string1, string2);
temp = pf(string1, string2);
temp = test(string1, string2);
```